# "Classical" Sobolev inequality

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Is the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality) for the Sobolev inequality correct?

> Let $p$, so that $1 \leq p < \infty$ and $\Omega$ a subset with at least one bound. There then exists a constant $C$, depending only on $\Omega$ and $p$, so that, for every function $u$ of $W_0^{1,p}$,
>   $$ \|u\|_{L^{p} (\Omega)} \leq C \| \nabla u \|_{L^{p} (\Omega)}.$$

One can easily make the counterexample of $u \equiv 1$ on the interval $(0,1)$, which has gradient identically 0.

Comment: I think it says $u$ in $W_0^{1,p}$ right?

Comment: The zero in the subscript means vanishing at the boundary.

Comment: Also, the derivatives are understood in a weak sense. So, I'm not sure $1$ even has a weak derivative (looking at the definition of weak derivative).

Comment: Shouldn't weak derivatives match the classical derivative if the latter exists?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative  Judging from the formula, if this were the case, then the R.H.S. would have to be 0, which seems wrong.

Comment: Nevermind, below it says that if it has a derivative in the classical sense then that is its weak derivative. Seems strange to me.

Comment: @SquirtleSquad shouldn't seem strange since the weak definition can be derived from the classical one. Then uniqueness gives the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function $u$ satisfies $u \in W^{1,p}(0,1)$, but not $u \in W_0^{1,p}(0,1)$. Indeed, $u$ is continuous and has boundary values $1$. If it would be in $W_0^{1,p}(0,1) \cap C([0,1])$, it would satisfy $u(-1) = u(1) = 0$.